# Neyman pearson on discrete distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, neyman-pearson-lemma

[image]

[image]

I have found the ratio of h1 to h0 and the ratio is increasing .So we should reject H0 for large values of x.How should i find the critical region for such type of questions.It seems to me the rejection region is P(x>k)=α.How i determine k .Thank you.

Comment: Try to type out your questions and add the `self-study` tag.

Comment: This similar question might help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/386092/119261.

Comment: It mights sounds silly . But what is the significance of finding liklihood ratio of null and alternative hypothesis.Why should't i directly reject null hypothesis for all values of P(x<k)=α

Comment: In answer to your previous Comment, you were asked to make $\alpha = 0.1.$ // Finally got a version of my answer that I think/hope will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your Question is somewhat quirky. Possibly
that's on purpose to show you that likelihood ratio tests
do not always provide satisfactory results--especially when the distributions for $H_0$ and $H_1$ are too nearly alike.
I will return to this problem after looking at a likelihood ratio test that works more satisfactorily.

Consider a test of $H_0$ vs $H_1$ where discrete distributions on integers $0$ through $4$ are as shown
below, followed by the likelihood of the null distribution divided by the alternative distribution.

```
pdf.0; pdf.1; LR
[1] 0.410 0.410 0.153 0.025 0.002
[1] 0.008 0.076 0.264 0.412 0.240
[1] 51.250  5.395  0.580  0.061  0.008
```

We want a test with significance level not greater than
$0.1 = 10\%.$ If we reject for small values of the
likelihood ratio, then we can reject for LR < .1, which means rejecting for $X \ge 3.$

Then $$\alpha = P(\mathrm{Rej}|H_0) = P(X \ge 3|H_0)\\
= 0.025 + 0.002 = 0.025.$$ [If we tried to increase the
rejection region to include $X=3,$ then we would have $\alpha > 0.1.]$

It follows that the power of this test is
$$\pi = P(\mathrm{Rej}|H_1) = P(X \ge 3|H_1)\\ 
=0.412 + 0.240 = 0.662.$$

The figure below shows the two PDFs with $H_0$ in blue
and $H_1$ in brown. The rejection region is to the right
of the vertical dotted line. In the rejection region the blue bars (for $H_0)$ are relatively short and the red bars (for $H_1)$ are relatively tall. The distributions are sufficiently different that a reasonably useful
likelihood ratio test can be found.

```
plot(x-.02, pdf.0, type="h", lwd=2, col="blue")
 lines(x+.02, pdf.1, type="h", lwd=2, col="brown")
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v = 2.5, lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Now, we turn to the problem in your Question.
Under $H_0$ the PDF is given by `f.0` and
under $H_1$ by `f.1` for values $X = 1,2,3,4,5.$

```
f.0 = c( .1, .1, .1, .1, .6)
f.1 = c(.05,.06,.08,.09,.72)
like.rat = f.0/f.1;  round(like.rat, 2)
[1] 2.00 1.67 1.25 1.11 0.83
```

If we reject for small values of the likelihood ratio
then we reject when $X = 4,$ so the significance level
is $P(X=4|f_0) = 0.1$ (as requested). We cannot put the
$X$-value with the smallest likelihood ratio into the
rejection region because that would give $\alpha > 0.1.$

Accordingly, the power is $P(X=4|f_1) = 0.09,$ disappointingly small for practical use.

A useful likelihood ratio test is not possible because
the distributions described by $f_0$ and $f_1$ are not
much different from one another, as shown in the figure below.

[image]

*Notes:* (1) The distributions in the first example are roughly modeled after $\mathsf{Binom}(4, 0.2)$ and
$\mathsf{Binom}(4, 0.7).$ Rounded to three places and altered to sum to exactly $1.$

(2) If you know about randomized tests, then you could reject
with probability $1/6$ only for $X = 5$ (perhaps with the roll of a fair die) to get $\alpha=0.1.$ In that case, the power would be $0.72/6 = 0.18,$ which is better than $0.09$ with the non-randomized test above, but still not large enough to be
considered useful.

*References for randomized tests:* Mood, Graybill, Boes: *Intro. to the Theory of Statistics,* 3e (1974), p404;
Bain & Englehardt, *Intro. to Probability and Math. Statistics,* 2e (1992), p411. [Productive searching online is difficult because of conflation with 'randomization' tests, a different topic.]

Comment: Isn't the usual definition of likelihood ratio $\frac{f_1}{f_0}$ instead of $\frac{f_0}{f_1}$ the way you have it? One advantage in this problem is that the usual ratio takes on values $0.5, 0.6, 0.8, 0.9, 1.2$ without needing to invoke `round(like.rat,2)`.