# randomized Neyman-Pearson lemma for a discrete distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, neyman-pearson-lemma, discrete-distributions

We let $\Theta=\{0,1\}$, and $X$ be a discrete R.V with the following probability distribution:

| x | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $f(x;0)$ | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.02 | 0.86 |
| $f(x;1)$ | 0.14 | 0.12 | 0.10 | 0.08 | 0.06 | 0.04 | 0.02 | 0.44 |
| Ratio | 7 | 6 | 5 | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | 0.511 |

We want to use the theorem of Neyman-Pearson to find the most powerful test of size $\alpha=0.05$ for the hypothesis $H_0: \theta=0$ and $H_1: \theta=1$, and also I want to calculate the Type II error probability of this test(power?).

I have looked at some similar questions([Neyman pearson on discrete distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467505/neyman-pearson-on-discrete-distribution) and [Most powerful test for deciding probability mass function](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386092/most-powerful-test-for-deciding-probability-mass-function)), however I'm still struggling to understand what to do in this case, especially since I need an exact value, so the test has to be randomized. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want high probability of rejection of $H_0$ when $H_1$ is true, which would lead to the choice of values of $x$ with high values of $f(x;1)$. On the other hand, every time you include a value $x$ in your critical region you increase the power of your test  by $f(x;1)$ but also the probability of unduly rejecting $H_0$ by $f(x;0)$. You want maximum power, but not exceeding your pre-assigned "budget" of Type I error of $\alpha=0.05$.

If you were buying potatos in a market, you would take first the offers of those which give you the most potatos per unit of money. Similarly here, you would pick for your critical region those values of $x$ which give you the maximum ratio $f(x;1)/f(x;0)$ (conveniently calculated for you in the last row).

Here, that would lead to picking $\{1,2\}$ for a total expense of 0.04. Adding $x=3$ to these would exceed your budget, so you add only "one half" of $x=3$, by playing a lottery which rejects the null hypothesis one half of the time when you observe $x=3$. With this device, your total probability of unduly rejecting $H_0$ will be $\alpha=0.05$ as required.