# Neyman Pearson Lemma for non-monotonic discrete likelihood function

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Let $X \sim f_j, j = 0,1,$ where
$$\begin{array}{ c c c }
 x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 f_0(x) & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} \\  
 f_1(x) & {1 \over 6} & {1 \over 4} & {1 \over 6} & {1 \over 4} & {1 \over 6}     
\end{array}$$

(a) Find the form of the MP test of its size.

**My approach:**

$$
H_0: f = f_0 \\
H_1: f = f_1
$$

According to Neyman Pearson lemma
$$\varphi(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & f_1(x) > kf_0(x) \\
\gamma(x) & f_1(x) = kf_0(x) \\
0 & f_1(x) < kf_0(x)
\end{cases}
$$
We can define likelihood ratio as follow:
$$\begin{array}{ c c c }
 x & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ 
 f_0(x) & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} & {1 \over 5} \\  
 f_1(x) & {1 \over 6} & {1 \over 4} & {1 \over 6} & {1 \over 4} & {1 \over 6} \\
 \lambda(x) & {5 \over 6} & {5 \over 4} & {5 \over 6} & {5 \over 4} & {5 \over 6} \\     
\end{array}$$

The size can be defined as
$$\underset{sup\ \theta \in \theta_0}{\alpha(\theta)} = \alpha = P_0(\lambda(x) > k)$$

How can I proceed forward? I have no idea how to proceed forward in case of non-montonic discrete functions.

Comment: Please do not [cross-post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3792755/321264). Decide where you want to ask.

Comment: Similar: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/386092/119261.